# Нужна ли запятая? 4

Tags: пунктуация

Или новая модель развития, — или всё поглощающий кризис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая?

Не нужна.

*Или новая модель развития — или всё поглощающий кризис.*

Возможен и другой вариант:

*Или новая модель развития, или — всё поглощающий кризис.*

Comment: Спасибо. А запятая, которая здесь ставится между однородными членами, соединенными повторяющимися союзами, значит, поглощается тире?

Comment: А в таком предложении: Продукт или технология не могут быть конкурентоспособными в рамках национальной экономики — но только на глобальном уровне.

Comment: И здесь всё правильно. См.: _§ 84... Возможно выделение присоединительных членов и при помощи тире, особенно в конечной позиции._ http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Возможна и третья (наиболее русская) версия написания, убирающая совершенно ненужное тире, но сохраняющая запятую:

```
Или новая модель развития, или всепоглощающий кризис.
```